# How to get log for TDengine JDBC connector?

Tags: tdengine

With TDengine JDBC connector, when there is an error happening, I cannot find any log on both server side and client side even if I change the log level to 143(trace) in /etc/taos/taos.cfg.
What should I do to get the log for JDBC connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update following options in the config file: /etc/taos/taos.cfg on your JDBC client

```
asyncLog    0
debugFlag   135
```

Restart your jdbc application, you will see full logs for JDBC connector, to see more log details, you can update debugFlag to 143